# Why GridView add CheckBoxes automatically in concerned column during importing excel file to GridView, which has bool value columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I've a page where I upload a excel sheet and display the values on gridview. Excel sheet has 5 columns, in which 3 columns have bool value (TRUE/FALSE). All thing are going right but Gridview add checkboxes in concerned column, where excel sheet has bool value. Gridview is as

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None" style="margin-top: 20px;width:100%;margin-bottom:20px; text-align:left"
    >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#FF9F00" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#FF9F00" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FF9F00" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FF9F00" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFD300" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FF0000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFD300" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#FFD300" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFD300" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#FFD300" />
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SN">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and look as [image]

And excel sheet:-
[image]

Comment: My problem is I am not able to find the value of boolean cell.

Comment: If you are exporting a gridview as Excel, then there are no booleans,only strings. Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files to maintain type safety, like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Comment: I just want to find the check box value weather it is checked or not, but as I've not add these pragmatically/manually, so how can find those controls?

Comment: But that has nothing to do with excel. You either check controls in a gridview or export an Excel. If you want to check that in Excel you can't because they are all string values.

Answer (score -1):

As long as your Model contains properties for the bool columns, you can just bind those properties to the checkbox in the DataGrid. I have trouble sometimes when trying to bind to the DataGrid Checkbox, so I do something like this.

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SOME_COLLECTION, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10" CanUserAddRows="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Material" Binding="{Binding MATERIAL_PROPERTY}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding QUANTITY_PROPERTY}" IsReadOnly="True" />

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Inspection?">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate> 
                    <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Path=INSPECTION_PROPERTY, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MRC?">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Path=MRC_PROPERTY, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Advance?">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ADVANCE_PROPERTY, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

This will bind each row's to that models bool property. Checking and unchecking the boxes will undate the property of the model, and you can pull the values from the Collection of properties found in your View Model.

Comment: OP is talking about an `asp:GridView`. Not winforms/xaml.